# Having problem while running a code in Codeblocks 13.12

Tags: code-blocks

I can't build and run any object code by using my Code:blocks compiler (version 13.12). Whenever I open Code:blocks there is shown an environment problem which says,

> Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for GNU GCC Compiler.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to settings in the upper part
2. Click compiler
3. Choose reset to defaults.

Comment: This worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think GCC is not properly installed in your system

Type this in terminal:

```
gcc --version
```

If you dont see any version number then, type:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc && sudo apt-get install g++
```